# special character in #define macro

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, macros, porting

I am new to C++ and facing one easy problem mention below.
in visual C++ 2008, i am trying to #define something like

```
#define fromThis*  toThisPtr
#define fromThis   toThisObj
```

I am porting some code that is written in linux and need to port in accordance to winapi. The error which i am getting 
something like this.

```
 error C2008: '*' : unexpected in macro definition
 warning C4005: 'fromThis' : macro redefinition
 see previous definition of 'fromThis'
```

I need to redefine fromThis* and fromThis during preprocessing time. Is special character in #define macro are not allowed?
 How can i work this code out?

---

EDIT-1:
I am looking out possible solution to this. I am trying to repalce *fromThis to 'toThisPtr'. One suggested solution is use of typedefs. Which i did like below.

```
typedef toThisPtr   fromThis*;
typedef toThisObj   fromThis;
```

Now with this solution the error which i am getting is this:

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C2059: syntax error : ';'
error C2040: 'iovec' : 'toThisObj' differs in levels of indirection from 'toThisPtr'

can typedef be the siolution to this problem. What are the std way to replace fromThis* to change into toThisPtr?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx) for `#define` says its first argument is an identifier. Identifiers can only contain letters, digits and underscores and must not start with a digit.

Therefore, `fromThis*` is not a valid identifier, and you cannot `#define` it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that, nor should you. :)

For this, I'd personally use `typedef`s instead of macros.

```
typedef toThisPtr fromThis*
typedef toThisObj fromThis
```

and then just do a replace all.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but i got error in vs2008 | 
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'|
error C2059: syntax error : ';'                   |
error C2040: 'iovec' : 'toThisObj' differs in levels of indirection from 'toThisPtr' |
is is also wrong using '*' in typedef? Is there any std way to replace fromThis* to toThisPtr.

Comment: `typedef` instructions must end in semicolon `;`. Another advantage of `typedef` vs `#define` is that the first one belongs to namespaces, the second one is just like a "_search and replace_".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you've just got it backwards

```
#define toThisPtr fromThis*
#define toThisObj fromThis
```

This defines two macros called toThisPtr and toThisObj. Otherwise I've having a really hard time understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: He wants to have `fromThis*` replaced by `toThisPtr` during preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use * in a name.
See the excerpt from the documentation:

> You may define any valid identifier as a macro, even if it is a C
>   keyword
>
> A valid identifier is a sequence of one or more letters, digits or
>   underscore characters (_). Neither spaces nor punctuation marks or
>   symbols can be part of an identifier. Only letters, digits and single
>   underscore characters are valid. In addition, variable identifiers
>   always have to begin with a letter.